# Prefill form field with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, attribution

I'm prefilling an empty hidden field of a form with tag manager. I'm using this code:

```
 <script>
document.getElementById("input_6_13").value = "{{Cookie - utm_medium}}";
document.getElementById("input_44_13").value = "{{Cookie - utm_medium}}";
</script>
```

If I remove the second line it works. If I leave both lines it doesn't. There are two separate forms that have a field that needs to be filled in with the same variable.

Side note: I used this guide to set it up: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/enrich-form-submission-data-with-google-tag-manager/ but edited it to use cookies so I can save the data for a longer period.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JS console?

Comment: i would guess (since you didnt share the forms HTML) that you have ID's that repeat themselves and they have to be unique.

Comment: do both forms exist at the same time?  if not then you will get undefined error

Comment: I do get an error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:44
    at gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:963
    at Object.c [as __html] (gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:965)
    at Bc (gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:855)
    at h (gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:881)
    at gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:808
    at Array.<anonymous> (gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:883)
    at Array.<anonymous> (gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:882)
    at bf (gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:891)
    at cf (gtm.js?id=GTM-TPVJWW:893)

The forms are on separate pages.

Comment: @Pete the forms are on separate pages.

Comment: That's why then you can't do `.value` on an object that is null - you will need to run the code separately for each page

Comment: @Pete so I would have to create an additional tag in Tag Manager or can I run it in the same tag twice?

Comment: @Pete I created an additional tag and now it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, went to the shop!  Good to hear you solved it